# Passing a variable in OPENJSON WITH statement

Tags: json, sql-server, variables, ssms, dynamic-sql

Below script calls an API with base and other currency as input and gets foreign exchange(FX) value from its response. While reading the response from API we have to specify '$.rates.GBP' in openjson statement to read the value of FX (last statement of below script). I am not able to pass this as a parameter to make SampleValue dynamic. I tried using dynamic SQL but did not succeed.

Please help.

SQL:

```
SELECT  *
FROM OPENJSON((select Json_table from @json), N'$')
WITH (   
      SampleValue nvarchar(max) '$.rates.GBP' ,   
      SampleDate DATE '$.date'
      ) ;

    /*DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    'SELECT  *  FROM OPENJSON((select Json_table from @json), N''$'') WITH (           SampleValue  nvarchar(max)  ''$.rates.GBP'',  SampleDate DATE ''$.date'' ) ;'

 select @SQL; 
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

      DECLARE @SQLstring NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'SELECT  *
FROM OPENJSON((select Json_table from @json), N''$'') WITH (   
      SampleValue nvarchar(max) '+ ''''+ @param + ''''+ ' ,   
      SampleDate DATE'  + ''''+ '$.date'  + '''' + ' ) ;'

      select @SQLstring ; 
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLstring ;*/
```

Comment: `OPENJSON`, not "OPENJ**A**SON" ;)

Comment: Why are you using those really old OA procedures?

Comment: I tried CLR but as per my research it requires c# or any programming language. I want to use only sql

Comment: @RuhiAfreen Can you post the value of `(select Json_table from @json)` statement (the actual JSON)?

Comment: @Zhorov   {"base":"USD","rates":{"GBP":0.7739357155},"date":"2020-10-15"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below

```sql
select * into #Temp from @json
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    'SELECT  *  FROM OPENJSON((select * from #Temp), N''$'') WITH (           SampleValue  nvarchar(max)  ''$.rates.GBP'',  SampleDate DATE ''$.date'' ) ;'

 select @SQL; 
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to pass *a variable in OPENJSON WITH statement*, the following approach is a possible solution to your problem. You need to pass the JSON content as a parameter to `sp_executesql`:

Table:

```
DECLARE @json AS TABLE (Json_Table nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @json (Json_Table)
VALUES (N'{"base":"USD","rates":{"GBP":0.7739357155},"date":"2020-10-15"}')
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @jsonData nvarchar(max) = (SELECT Json_table FROM @json)
DECLARE @symbol char(3) = 'GBP'
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = CONCAT(
   N'SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@jsonData, N''$'') WITH (SampleValue nvarchar(max) ''$.rates.',
   @symbol,   
   N''', SampleDate date ''$.date'') j'
)   

PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@jsonData nvarchar(max)', @jsonData
```

Result:

```
SampleValue  SampleDate
0.7739357155 2020-10-15
```